# How does git commit -a differ from -a -m?

Tags: git

As per the title

**How does git commit -m differ from -a -m?**

I check out the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit) for **-a** but it's not very clean what they mean by

> Tell the command to automatically stage files that have been modified and deleted, but new files you have not told Git about are not affected.

Comment: The difference between those is `-m`, not `-a`. Look at the documentation for `-m`.

Comment: @Ryan you're right. there was a typo ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To commit changes (added before) we use following command

```
git commit -m "commit message"
```

To commit changes and automatically add modified files (doesn't add new files)

```
git commit -am "commit message"
```

Comment: Thinking about this way makes a lot of sense, have my vote for that ;-)

Comment: and so what's the difference between "add -A && commit -m" VS "commit -a -m"? I'm pretty sure there is difference as I usually get different results

Comment: @dragonmnl: `add -A` does add untracked files. `commit -a` is like `add -u` followed by `commit`.

Comment: thanks @Ryan. could you elaborate a bit on git add -a VS git commit -a VS "git add . && git commit -m "message""? I'm a bit confused? (final goal: commit all modified or deleted files which are not gitignored and specify a commit message)

Answer (score 0):

Simple: using -m allows you to specify a message for that commit.

That is all there is to this. Quoting your own link:

> Use the given `<msg>` as the commit message. If multiple -m options are given, their values are concatenated as separate paragraphs.